# How to return multiple elements in a single XPath query using Groovy

Tags: xpath, groovy

I would like to know if its possible using Xpath to return mutliple elements from a single Xpath query without the use of the union '|' operator?

The problem I have is that I want to return two elements that are at different levels of the XML structure (employment_information.person_id_external and job_information.start_date) in one Xpath query from the following XML:

```
<CompoundEmployee>
  <person>
    <person_id_external>21554</person_id_external>
    <employment_information>
      <start_date>2014-02-27</start_date>
      <job_information><end_date>2013-04-21</end_date><event>H</event><start_date>2012-09-28</start_date></job_information>
      <job_information><end_date>2013-04-26</end_date><event>5</event><start_date>2013-04-22</start_date></job_information>
      <job_information><end_date>9999-12-31</end_date><event>R</event><start_date>2014-02-27</start_date></job_information>
    </employment_information>
  </person>
  <person>
    <person_id_external>8265</person_id_external>
    <employment_information>
      <start_date>2000-10-02</start_date>
      <job_information><end_date>2014-10-24</end_date><event>5</event><start_date>2014-05-22</start_date></job_information>
      <job_information><end_date>2014-05-21</end_date><event>H</event><start_date>2000-10-02</start_date></job_information>
      <job_information><end_date>9999-12-31</end_date><event>5</event><start_date>2014-10-25</start_date></job_information>
    </employment_information>
  </person>
  <execution_timestamp>2015-05-05T08:17:51.000Z</execution_timestamp>
  <version_id>1502P0</version_id>
</CompoundEmployee>
```

and the XPath query I've written so far is:

```
XPath x = XPath.newInstance("/*/*/*/job_information[number(translate(start_date,'-','')) < number(translate(../start_date,'-','')) and (event = 'H' or event = 'R')]/start_date");

Employees = x.selectNodes(doc);

for (Element Employee : Employees) {

    fieldName = Employee.getName();
    fieldValue = Employee.getText();

    println ("Job Information Selection ${fieldName} = ${fieldValue}");
}
```

which works but only returns the job_information.start_date.  If I union the same query but return employment_information.person_id_external the query returns them on two rows - 1 row per union but I want them returned on the same row but as two fields, if that makes sense.  Can I do this?  And if so how do I do it?

Thanks,

Greg

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Concepts like row or field are not known to XPath, and all nodes in the result set are simply output as rows.